# Eclipse IDE search definition error (Progress View)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a Java EE developer and keep running into an issue with the Eclipse IDE. Whenever I am working with a JSP or Javascript file it tries to

"Search for a definition" and "Synchronizing script resources with Tern Server"

[image]

I attached an image of the issue. If anyone has ran into this please let me know. 
All suggestions are welcomed.

This issue is constantly slowing down Eclipse and I have not found anything on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder/file and then: /properties/Ressource/ -> check derived. Look likes it work for me for the moment, but that's not 100% sure.